# Does [tag:development] mean "Asking for closure"?

Tags: discussion, tags

As Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange is not for Android development, why is there still [development](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/development) this tag? Does this tag, to some extent, mean "Asking to close this question"?
For me, I will raise a recommend closure flag as soon as I see a development question, so I think this tag is just for closure (and maybe migration?).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it's mainly there so that when someone tries to ask a development question, they can see the tag wiki excerpt:

> Development questions are off-topic. Do not ask them here.

That said, if you browse that tag, you can see that there are some questions there which are about using Android as a development platform, which is OK. If your question is about using Android, it's OK, even if you're a developer or you want to use it for things related to software development.

For example, there are some questions in that tag about using Android to write Python code for use on other platforms. They're relevant to our community because the same issues might come up with other text editing tasks. Obviously if the question were along the lines of "I used my Android phone to write this Python code ... but it doesn't work. What's wrong with my code?" that question would be off-topic, because then it's not about using Android any more.